# How to properly Select DTO projections using JPA Join tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have one entity and a one to one relationship. Now i'm looking for the best way to retrieve specific fields from both tables using a projection.

In my first attempt i've tried:

```
"SELECT NEW br.com.domain.order.Order( " +
                "o.id," +
                "o.description," +
                "p.payment) " +
                "FROM Order o
```

Using this way i have a single constructor inside Order entity, to retrieve only these 3 fields. But now i have N+1 queries.

The second option is the follow:

```
"SELECT NEW br.com.domain.order.OrderDTO( " +
                    "o.id," +
                    "o.description," +
                    "p.status,
                     p.locationId,
                     p.value) " +
                    "FROM Order o JOIN  o.payment p
```

This works great but i have to create a DTO class.

How can i do something like this:

```
"SELECT NEW br.com.domain.order.Order( " +
                        "o.id," +
                        "o.description," +
                        "p.status,"+
                        "p.locationId,"+
                        "p.value)"
```

It's necessary to create a constructor inside both entities to load all properties?

Comment: huh? whatever class you put in the `NEW` constructor expression has to have that constructor. Can't get simpler

Comment: But the first class must call the second class constructor, right @DN1?

Comment: The first class can do whatever it likes, a JPA query will simply call the constructor defined in the JPQL. Only you know your classes, they are not present in this "question"